# Нейронные сети, угроза в сетевом трафике

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, keras

В общем у меня есть задача, распознать угрозу в сетевом трафике. Угроза представляет собой последовательность TCP, UDP-потоков. Их необходимо разметить и подать на вход нейронной сети. У меня есть таблица CSV, который состоит из отдельных признаков таких как duration, reverse_packets, reverse_bytes, direct_packets, direct_bytes, total_packets, total_bytes, vulnerability. Я могу эту строку запихнуть в нейронную сеть без проблем. Меня интересует следующее, есть ли способы(разновидности нейросетей) когда можно на вход подать несколько строк(пакетов) и разметить как одна vulnerability? наверняка это возможно сделать.

Comment: @MaxU я конечно всё понимаю, что это абстрактная задача. Но может есть люди которые шарят в нейронных сетях. Моих знаний сейчас хватает только на ввод отдельных потоков в нейронную сеть. Я не умею их группировать.

Comment: @MaxU задаю по-моему ощущению вполне конкретный вопрос , у меня есть таблица CSV, который состоит из отдельных признаков таких как duration, reverse_packets, reverse_bytes, direct_packets, direct_bytes, total_packets, total_bytes, vulnerability. Я могу эту строку запихнуть в нейронную сеть без проблем. Меня интересует, есть ли способы когда можно на вход подать несколько строк(пакетов) и разметить как одна vulnerability.

Comment: Вот это уже совсем другое дело! Теперь это похоже на более  конкретный вопрос. Только надо перенести текст вопроса из комментариев в вопрос.

Comment: @MaxU вопрос перенес

Answer (score 0):

Это не только наверняка это можно сделать, это уже более-менее успешно делают более 10 лет. И с помощью нейронных сетей и с помощью других методов ML. Более того, скажу, что анализ именно потоковых представлений трафика чаще всего проводят все-таки методами кластерного анализа. Хотя и другими методами тоже. Для анализа сырых данных чаще применяют либо анализ временных рядов, либо LSTM сети, хотя есть и очень интересные работы по применению других методов. Более того, оказывается, что для выявления разных информационных угроз и инцидентов (и как частный случай -  разных видов атак) лучше срабатывают разные методы.

Литературы - море, правда в большинстве своем на английском. У меня на флешке гигабайт 15 и книг и статей, да в закладках сотни сайтов.

В качестве первого ознакомления (и что-бы попроще, на русском) можно глянуть книгу

http://rucont.ru/efd/214235

Там не все бесспорно, но хоть с  темой ознакомитесь.
Вот также очень достойная книга

[https://www.amazon.com/Intrusion-Detection-Learning-Electrical-Engineering/dp/1848164475](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1848164475)

Старенький, но неплохой обзор 
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220468036_Network_intrusion_detection_system_A_machine_learning_approach

(есть и более новые, просто я сейчас в далеке от своей "флеш"-библиотеки).

Ну, вот тут именно про применение LSTM, если очень хочется:

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/330475823_LSTM_for_Anomaly-Based_Network_Intrusion_Detection

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332824465_Intrusion_Detection_by_Deep_Learning_with_TensorFlow

https://ir.lib.uwo.ca/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=7745&context=etd

https://journals.nauss.edu.sa/index.php/JISCR/article/view/454

А вообще -  тема неисчерпаема. Если что -  спрашивайте.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ! можешь подсказать, я вроде бы прочитал про keras и входные данные для сети. Но не могу понять как мне сформировать обучающую выборку.

train_x = {
 {
 {attr1,attr2,attr3,attr4}
 {attr1,attr2,attr3,attr4}
 {attr1,attr2,attr3,attr4}
 } 
 {
 {attr1,attr2,attr3,attr4}
 {attr1,attr2,attr3,attr4}
 }
 {
 {attr1,attr2,attr3,attr4}
 {attr1,attr2,attr3,attr4}
 {attr1,attr2,attr3,attr4}
 {attr1,attr2,attr3,attr4}
 }
 etc
}

train_y = {CVE1,CVE2,CVE3, etc} в таком формате будет работать? можете пожалуйста привести небольшой код для LSTM сети.

Comment: Что за данные?   Это временные ряды?  Или это  для кластерного анализа," естественного" инструмента для анализа сессий, как я писал выше? Ничего не понятно. А про небольшой код для LSTM на Keras -  что вы имеете ввиду? Ну вот тут гляньте - https://keras.io/examples/lstm_stateful/  - вполне себе небольшой код.

Comment: На подобии временных рядов(по крайней мере я хочу такие данные подать на вход), обязательны ли для временных рядов timestamp? нет, не для кластерного анализа, хочу для LSTM.

Comment: "обязательны ли для временных рядов timestamp" - естественно, иначе это будут уже не временные ряды.

Comment: в моих данных не будет timestamp, мне важна порядок потоков tcp,udp. Например CVE-XXXXX, 4 прямых потоков и 1 обратный. Походу мне нужен RNN сеть.Или можно создать искусствено timestamp в зависимости от порядка.

Comment: Во-первых,любой поток имеет как минимум момент начала - вот вам и timestamp. Более того, интервалы между моментами начала потоков между парой  IP есть достаточно интересный диагностический признак. Прямой, обратный - это уже признак. Т.о. у вас появляется некоторый паттерн описания нормальных и аномальных потоков.  Задача для вновь появившегося набора потоков выделить те, которые относятся к классу аномальных. И тут, как раз, мы и переходим из области временных рядов об область кластерного анализа. О чем я и говорил с самого начала.

Comment: привет, можешь выложить собранную литературу в публичный доступ, я даже банально не могу открыть статьи из-за того что необходимо подтвердить членство, указать что-то еще. Было бы круто, спасибо!